# BeanFieldGroup vs FieldGroup with BeanItem?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

When binding fields to a bean there are two ways:

1. Use a `FieldGroup` and wrap the bean in a `BeanItem`:

   ```
   final FieldGroup fieldGroup = new FieldGroup(new BeanItem<DataBean>(dataBean));
   ```
2. Use a `BeanFieldGroup`, in this case the bean will also be wrapped into a `BeanItem`under the hoods:

   ```
   final BeanFieldGroup<DataBean> beanBinder = new BeanFieldGroup<>(DataBean.class);
   beanBinder.setItemDataSource(dataBean);
   ```

IMHO using a `FieldGroup` is actually simpler, is there any advantage in using a `BeanFieldGroup`?

Answer (score 2):

BeanFielGroup is an extension of FieldGroup, In addition to the properties of FieldGroup it also has support for

- Java Bean Validation API 1.0 (JSR-303)
- Handles Nested Properties.
- Certain Helper methods to add various fields.

Based on your use case you can prefer either of it. If you are managing the Form/layout via Pojo's I would suggest you should use BeanFieldGroup instead of FieldGroup and if you have loosely coupled properties, I would suggest FieldGroup over BeanFieldGroup